# How to avoid having to fetch Account Id of logged in user at every transaction. MVC4 + Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

I have a web app that uses MVC Controllers strictly to render HTML 5 and Javascript (Knockout JS) interface.

The login is handled by a "Login" MVC Contoller:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Once logged into the app, requests are made to my application via AJAX calls to my WEB API controllers (RESTful API)

I then ensure that the user is allowed to perform the action that he's trying to do by filtering repo calls based on the user's AccountId. My problem I'm trying to solve is avoiding having to make a repo call to get the accountId at every single transaction.

Consider the following simplified REST endpoint:

```
    // GET api/tasks
    public IEnumerable<Dto.Get.tasks> Get()
    {
        long accountId = _accountRepository.FindBy(a => a.Name == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).Single().Id;
        var modelTasks= _taskRepository.Where(t => t.AccountId == accountId).ToList();
        return _taskModelConverter.Convert(modelTasks);
    }
```

The line **long accountId = _accountRepository.FindBy(a => a.Name == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).Single().Id;** is peppered throughout my code.

I'd like to find a less "chatty" way getting my account id. Any ideas?

Comment: Is putting that code into a base controller property out of the question... ? Or is that still "chatty" in terms of database calls?

Answer (score 1):

Cool problem and glad to see you are thinking along these lines!  One easy option (but still chatty if you're not careful) is to store the account id in a cookie:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new Cookie("a_id", account_id));
```

But you will find that violates [all kinds of security rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_ID_Content_.28or_Value.29).  A better approach would be to encrypt the account id:

```
var accountBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(idString);
var encrypted = MachineKey.Protect(accountBytes, "Account Id");
var cookieValue = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
// Stuff that bad boy into a cookie
```

(Be sure to set a purpose when using [MachineKey.Protect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect.aspx) as this will add a bit of hashing to the value before encrypting it).

What I usually do is create a bit of custom authentication logic in my `Global.asax.cs` class which does the work of your `WebSecurity.Login` above.  A lot depends on how comfortable you are with writing that kind of code.

**Remember** to round-trip your cookies and set proper time-outs.  Also, try to keep any cookie you set to under 1.5k as described under "Minimize Request Size" on [this page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/request) - cookie and header size contribute significantly to request time when hitting RESTful endpoints!

Answer (score 0):

A base controller class is probably what you need in this instance. Of course it will mean that you still continue to call the database every time you redirect to a new view.